# having an issue with Array.reduce(). I have somewhat correct output. But I can't figure out the rest

Tags: javascript, codepen, array-reduce

Here are the instructions:

- Pretend that there is no **Array.filter()** method. Use **Array.reduce()** to filter out only the objects from the provided array with a **price** property of **10** or over.
- Pretend there there is no Array.filter() method, only Array.reduce().
  How would you use Array.reduce() to mimic the filter method, thus that
  from the array below, you can create a new array composed of only the objects
  from the original array that contain a price property of 10 and over?
  Part of the code has been completed for you.
  Complete the rest by uncommenting the return statement on line 36
  and writing the code for what to return when cur.price is >= 10.

This is what the expected output should be:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLVJP.png

This is what I have so far:

```
const gems = [
    { type: 'amethyst', price: 8 },
    { type: 'turquoise', price: 50 },
    { type: 'selenite', price: 2 },
    { type: 'topaz', price: 10 },
    { type: 'emerald', price: 500 }
]

const gemsOverTen = gems.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   if (cur.price < 10) return acc;
   if (cur.price >= 10) {
   return {
       ...acc,
        "type": cur.type, "price": cur.price
       }};
}, []);

console.log(gemsOverTen);
```

Here's my codepen as well:

https://codepen.io/alexiscodes21/pen/wvEVrew?editors=0011

Comment: You are returning an object, you are not pushing a new object onto an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const gems = [
    { type: 'amethyst', price: 8 },
    { type: 'turquoise', price: 50 },
    { type: 'selenite', price: 2 },
    { type: 'topaz', price: 10 },
    { type: 'emerald', price: 500 }
]



const gemsOverTen = gems.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur.price < 10) return acc;
  return [
    ...acc,
    {
      "type": cur.type,
      "price": cur.price
    }
  ];
}, []);

console.log(gemsOverTen);
```

if you do not need a fresh copy:

```js
const gems = [
    { type: 'amethyst', price: 8 },
    { type: 'turquoise', price: 50 },
    { type: 'selenite', price: 2 },
    { type: 'topaz', price: 10 },
    { type: 'emerald', price: 500 }
]

const gemsOverTen = gems.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur.price < 10) return acc;
  return [
    ...acc,
    cur
  ];
}, []);

console.log(gemsOverTen);
```

or just use push

```js
const gems = [
    { type: 'amethyst', price: 8 },
    { type: 'turquoise', price: 50 },
    { type: 'selenite', price: 2 },
    { type: 'topaz', price: 10 },
    { type: 'emerald', price: 500 }
]



const gemsOverTen = gems.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur.price >= 10) acc.push(cur);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(gemsOverTen);
```